# Finding an equation for the element of the $i^{\text{th}}$ row and $j^{\text{th}}$ column

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory

This is the question:

> If we have this infinitely large matrix
> $$\left[\begin{matrix}
> 1&3&6&10&15&\cdots\\
> 2&5&9&14&\cdots\\
> 4&8&13&\cdots\\
> 7&12&\cdots\\
> 11&\cdots\\
> \vdots \end{matrix}\right]$$
> Then find a formula for the element of the $i^{\text{th}}$ row and $j^{\text{th}}$ column

I found that the numbers are increasing diagonally and the increase in each number increments by $1$ for each row and the amount by which we increase in the first two terms also increases by $1$, but I don’t know how can I generalise this, can anyone please help.

Comment: The first row is simply the triangular numbers $n(n+1)/2$. You can get the second row by adding 1,2,3,4,5...to the elements of the first row at the same position. you can do the same with the elements of the 3rd row...

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

1. The first number of row $i$ is $1+\sum_{n=1}^{i-1}n$.
2. To go from element $(i, j)$ to element $(i, j+1)$ you need to add $i+j$.

I'll let you prove these facts and take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Let's write $A={a_{i,j}}$, with $i,j\ge 1$. From the $i$th row and $j$th column, move diagonally towards lower left side. To get to the first column, you need to do $j-1$ steps. That means you increase the number of rows by $j-1$ and the decrease the number of columns by $j-1$. Then $$a_{i,j}=a_{i+j-1,1}+j-1$$
The only thing you need to do now is to calculate the elements in the first column. You have $$a_{1,1}=1\\a_{n+1,1}=a_{n,1}+n$$

Comment: the elements of the first column are just the triangular numbers $n(n+1)/2$.

Comment: Correct. Depending on the context, you might need to prove this as well. The justification is that for each element in the first column you have the row number of elements on the upward diagonal, so you get $\sum_{k=1}^n k=n(n+1)/2$

Comment: the final formula can be expressed in terms of triangular numbers. If $(i,j)$ is (row, column) then $A_{i,j}= T_{j} + T_{j-1 +i-1} - T_{j-1}$.

Comment: I think the more elegant solution would be to write directly it in terms of row and column number